# disable one option from the multiple options of the select

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I created a contact form with the plugin contact form 7.
My problem is i want to disable one option from the multiple options of the select.
This is my code :

```
[select evenement class:form-control  "first-option" "second-option" ....]
```

Please tell me how can i fix this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way of doing this with Contact Form 7.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . if i add some js code can be resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add some custom javascript code to do this, you can add it right below your cf7 tag in your form,

```
[select evenement class:form-control  "first-option" "second-option" ....]
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
  'use strict';
  $(document).ready( function(){
    var $select =  $('.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.evenement select', 'form.wpcf7');
    $('option[value="first-option"]', $select).attr('disabled',true);
  });
})(jQuery)
</script>`
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Replacing the include_blank with first_as_label

```
first_as_label "choose one"
```

example :

```
[select menu-id first_as_label "Choose one..." "option one" "option two" "option 3"]
```

2- use this script to disable first option

```
(function ($) {
   'use strict';
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var $select = $('.wpcf7-select');
       $select.each(function(e){
         var first_option = $(this).find('option').first();
         if(first_option.attr('value') == ''){
           first_option.attr('disabled', true);
         }
     })
  });
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
  'use strict';
  $(document).ready( function(){
    var $option = $('option:contains("first-option")');
    $option.attr('disabled',true);
  });
})(jQuery)
</script>
```